# Report con un Subreport que es otro Report

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

Tengo un Report hecho en iReport, este report contiene una subreport el cual muestra un report, este subreport lo uso como cabecera.

El subreport contiene 2 componentes para imagenes y 2 parámetros, lo cuales son titulos (estos funcionan por que los paso por parámetro desde el report principal), mi problema surje en las imágenes las cuales no se muestran cuando lo lanzo desde java.

El subreport tiene una query donde obtenemos los fields de las imágenes (tipo inputstream) , al hacer preview en iReport si se muestra, pero a la hora de lanzarlo desde baja el proceso lanza un error diciendo: "Imagen_Izq no encontrado".

Acontinuación dejo adjunto una imagen donde muestro el proceso de ejecución.
*Recuerdo que desde java hago una llamada al report y se supone que el report debería realizar la consulta de la imagenes por ella misma ya que en la opción de query se le asignó su correspondiente consulta para obtenerlas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo lo que haria es pasarle al report un inputstream(este contiene la imagen) y despues pasarle como parametro a los subreports este inputstream y ya despues lo pintas

Comment: Eso ya lo hice como alternativa, ya que el informe se está usando actualmente, pero me exigen que no se pase las imagenes desde java como parámetro, si no lo que digo en mi cuestion, que el propio report la cargue con la query que se le configuró :P

Comment: Te lo dejo como comentario porque ya validaras si te sirve o no, jasper propone el siguiente ejemplo para la carga de imagenes desde base de datos http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-images-stored-database-reports

Comment: Ya he probado ese tutorial, me genera el archivo (un pdf) pero las imágenes no salen, es más paso por parámetro al subreport unos textos los cuales si salen, por lo que el subreport esta bien por una parte, pero las imagenes que se suponen que vienen desde la propia query que está dentro del report (subreport) se deberían generar, digo yo.
En el log me sale esto: 
WARN JRJdbcQueryExecuter:128 - The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.